# How to test an XML attribute against a column value instead of a parameter in TSQL?

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xpath

How should I change the following query if I want to select all the rows that has the 'Value' attribute equals to t2.CookieID instead of @value parameter?

```
SELECT (list of columns) 
FROM dbo.MyTable t1 
INNER JOIN dbo.MyTable t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
WHERE t2.[Description]
         .exist('/Parent/Child/SpecialCode[@Value=sql:variable("@value")]') = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [`sql:column("CookieId")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191214.aspx)